# Best practices to avoid binding errors

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Do you know a systematic approach to avoid binding errors in WPF projects?

As they grow it's getting impractical to rely on the output window and it is a pain while refactoring, that you can easily break bindings by renaming properties in the view model.

Right now I'm using a complex procedure of exposing the property paths as static properties and use them in my binding. This way resharper helps me renaming the static references to my properties, if i rename them.

I consider to switch to [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors) approach to get an easier procedure. But I would loose the renaming assistance of resharper by this.

Is it worthwhile? Do you have better patterns?

Comment: Is not much but I use PrestationTraceLevel High to at least see a warning in debug mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to locate the source of a binding error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480569/how-to-locate-the-source-of-a-binding-error)

Comment: See [here some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8480651/485076)

Comment: That post is about what to do if you have binding errors. I would rather like to avoid them. Especially while refactoring. I should put more emphasis on this in the question.

Comment: use a framework that has a viewmodellocator pattern where you can specify a basic path from the usercontrol and where you can then send parameters to that controller. so then the calling controls are decoupled from the binding. i looking to do something similar myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper helps here somewhat.  If it can figure out the type for an element's `DataContext`, then it will verify that you're binding to properties that actually exist.  If it can't figure out the type, it will prompt you to set a [d:DataContext](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/) for the element.

Comment: Since which version does resharper support this? I didn't find that feature in 5.1.

Comment: I'm on version 6, so I guess that's when it was introduced.

Comment: Cool, I will give the new version a try.