# Information when DynamicResource could not be found during runtime?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In my current project I have a quite large WPF based application with lots of Static and DynamicResources.
Because of many refactorings and changes in the past there are lots of DynamicResources that can not be found during runtime and therefore no value is applied.

What I like to do is run the application and get an output, exception or whatever when a DynamicResource could not be found.

I have tried to build a DefaultTraceListener and a Converter that checks for unused DynamicResources, but to no avail.

Does anyone have a solution for me on how to achieve that?

Example:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="myStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource myStyle1}">DynamicResource exists</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource myStyle3}">DynamicResource does not exist</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

How can I be informed during runtime that myStyle3 does not exist?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you still using WPF Inspector as your go-to option for discovering any missing Dynamic Resources?  Sadly WPF Inspector crashes for me, as reported by another user [here](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/workitem/1172), so I'm checking to see if you've found any other viable options (I haven't found Snoop to be helpful for this issue).

Comment: Just tested it and it still works fine for me. WPF Inspector 0.9.9 and I am attaching to the application that is run from Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools that show you witch binding doesn't work..

- WPF Inspector is my favorite tool, take a look. [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)
- [Snoop utility](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is one of those. In short - in the top right corner you'll find DropDown list which allows filter visuals, just select Visuals with binding Error. Source: [How to locate the source of a binding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480569/how-to-locate-the-source-of-a-binding-error)
- In Visual Studio, you can enable all exceptions (with binding errors) in the Debug menu, Exceptions, then check everything.

But I don't know if it's exactly what you want, let other people answer this...

Comment: Thanks a ton for your recommendations! 

WPF Inspector had exactly what I needed. There's a rule for "unresolved dynamic resources".