# How to find the faulty binding within a huge view with many bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, data-binding

I'm running a UI test against a view, with many bindings. Unfortunately this test fails with the following error:

```
Test method MyExampleProject.UI.Tests.ExampleView.CancelCommand threw exception: 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.
    at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.CreateBindingExpression(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Binding binding, BindingExpressionBase parent)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feChild, FrameworkContentElement fceChild, Int32 childIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Int32 i, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(UncommonField`1 dataField, ItemStructList`1& valueLookupList, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, Boolean styleLookup, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromTemplatedParent(DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, Boolean isDetach, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplate(DependencyObject container, Object currentObject)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(Object createdObject, DependencyObject& rootObject, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass45_0.<LoadOptimizedTemplateContent>b__2(Object sender, XamlObjectEventArgs args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnBeforeProperties(Object value)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(Context ctx, IntPtr ctxID, Int32 appDomainID, InternalCrossContextDelegate ftnToCall, Object[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossContextChannel.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ..
```

As far as I understand the error, there is a two-way binding, which is read-only or there is no given path. There are so many bindings in this view. Is there an indicator or something, which helps me to find the faulty binding?

Comment: Visual studio is pretty bad with showing binding errors, like you already know the Output window is the only way. A lot of people recommend Snoop, an application where you can track bindings individually with ease, I have not used it yet. but here is a link , https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you @JohnChris! I'll check it out.

Comment: Ill post my comment as an answer, if you like the app, please mark it as a good answer:)

Comment: Actually the error is caused by a two-way binding without `Path` or `XPath` specified. So I'd start with looking for `{Binding}`, then `{Binding RelativeSource=...}`, `{Binding ElementName=...}` and so on. Luckily there is a limited number of possibilities, and not so many of them. As far as other ways proceeding I cannot think of any given only this error message.

Comment: You can also construct regex which will match {Binging ...} without Path inside and use that.

Comment: @Grx70: Thank you for your comment. The problem is caused by a `{Binding}`. Is there really no other way to find out, which is the faulty one, except commenting out parts of the view and trying it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend this library:

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfBindingErrors

GitHub: https://github.com/bblanchon/WpfBindingErrors

It helps out a lot, as it can convert 'binding errors' into runtime exceptions. Once the code breaks, the exception will tell you what exactly is broken.

Just install it via NuGet, and attach:

```
BindingExceptionThrower.Attach();
```

Comment: no problem.. if you do gated check-ins, you can add this as a gate so that your current build will never have any binding exceptions. :D

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio is pretty bad with showing binding errors, like you already know the Output window is the only way. A lot of people recommend Snoop, an application where you can track bindings individually with ease, I have not used it yet. but here is a link,

http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com

**UPDATE:**  Found a previous post with a good answer, explaining more than I could,

[How to locate the source of a binding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480569/how-to-locate-the-source-of-a-binding-error)